# SASS CSS animation

Tags: css, sass, css-transitions, css-transforms

I was wondering how do I set the list element in SASS to begin with `display:none` and then at the start of the animation make it `display:block` and then change the `background-color:#fff` to white at the end of the animation at 100%

[Demo Here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BeoLH)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `display:none` because your elements will not be able to receive the animation styles. Instead I would use `visibility: hidden`. Also, if want your styles to persist after the animation is complete, then you should use `animation-fill-mode: forwards`. [**See demo here**](http://codepen.io/myajouri/pen/zxbak).

Answer (score 0):

I am not very sure what exactly your animation will look like.

But tried to make it as a reference to you to solve your issue:

Here is the DEMO[enter link description here](http://codepen.io/jzheng/pen/zsyFt)

Comment: The problem is it fades back to 0 opacity when it should be 1